# Helm 3: x509 error when connecting to local Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I'm a perfect **noob** with K8s. I installed [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) and [Helm](https://helm.sh/) using `snap` to experiment locally. I wonder whether my current issue comes from the use of `snap` (purpose of which is encapsulation, from what I understood)

### Environment

Ubuntu 20.04LTS

```sh
helm version                                                                            
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
kubectl version     
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.4-1+6f17be3f1fd54a", GitCommit:"6f17be3f1fd54a88681869d1cf8bedd5a2174504", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-23T21:16:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.14.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.4-1+6f17be3f1fd54a", GitCommit:"6f17be3f1fd54a88681869d1cf8bedd5a2174504", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-23T21:17:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.14.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```sh
kubectl config get-contexts                                                             
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER            AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         microk8s   microk8s-cluster   admin
```

### Post install set up

```sh
microk8s enable helm3
```

Kubernetes is up and running

```sh
kubectl cluster-info 
Kubernetes master is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

### Problem while connecting `helm` to `microk8s`

```sh
helm ls --kube-token ~/token --kube-apiserver https://127.0.0.1:16443
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get https://127.0.0.1:16443/version?timeout=32s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

How can I tell `helm`

- to trust `microk8s` certs or
- to ignore this verification step

From what I read, I may overcome this issue by pointing to kube's config using `--kubeconfig`.

```sh
helm ls --kube-token ~/token --kube-apiserver https://127.0.0.1:16443 --kubeconfig /path/to/kubernetes/config
```

In the context of `microk8s` installed with `snap`, I am not quite sure what this *conf file* is nor where to find it.

- `/snap/microk8s/1503` ?
- `/var/snap/microk8s/1503` ?

Comment: microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config , try this command. You will have kubeconfig at the path where helm looks for which is $HOME/.kube/config

Comment: let me know if it works or not

Comment: Worked like a charm! Would you like to write a complete answer I would thumb up ? (I can write it)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Helm looks for kubeconfig at this path $HOME/.kube/config.

Please run this command

> microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config

This will save the config at required path in your directory and shall work

Reference Link [here](https://webcloudpower.com/use-kubernetics-locally-with-microk8s/)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying the same command without the --raw option and it didn't work. The "raw" option includes the certificates in the config file as well.

Comment: This also works with k3s, by using `kubectl config view --raw > ~/.kube/config`

Answer (score 0):

Please try exporting kubeconfig file using following command:
export KUBECONFIG=/var/snap/microk8s/current/credentials/client.config

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using WSL with docker desktop with k8s running in docker desktop but helm running in WSL a very similar command as provided by Tarun will also work.

Assuming you are running the Windows version of kubectl

```
➜  which kubectl.exe 
➜    /mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/kubectl.exe
➜  which kubectl 
➜    kubectl: aliased to /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/kubectl.exe


➜  kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config
```