# Helm, Docker - add repo failing inside a docker container but working outside

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I am having issues with adding repos with helm on a docker container.
The command I am trying to run is: `helm repo add dask https://helm.dask.org/`. The output from running it in the docker container is:

```
Error: looks like "https://helm.dask.org/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get "https://helm.dask.org/index.yaml": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried the same command outside of the docker container and I am getting the right output (I am working on MacOS Catalina and I have installed helm with Homebrew):

```
"dask" has been added to your repositories
```

I tried looking online ([Helm 3: x509 error when connecting to local Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050980/helm-3-x509-error-when-connecting-to-local-kubernetes), [docker container ssl certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates), https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/issues/1637). the last resource is pointing to adding the same local certificates of the host running the container, however I have not been able to do that.

I have also tried the stable chart repo with no luck (`helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable`).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: If I add this to the `helm add repo`, `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` the repo is added correctly. Of course this does not solve the bigger problem as I would like to have the right certificates in place.

Comment: Are there any configured proxies?

Comment: Hi @MaartenDev, so initially I though it was the VPN I am on, as outside it, the docker container is able to pull the repo. However, the host is able to pull the repo on VPN as well. Hope this help.

Comment: Hello, could you please add the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are you doing this from Kubernetes cluster (like within Docker Desktop with Kubernetes) or pure Docker container).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Dockerfile's base image, you can use your respective package manager, to include common/well-known certificate authority certificates within your container.

For example, for an Ubuntu based image:
`RUN apt add ca-certificates`.

Are you getting errors when trying to add common CA certificates to the container?

The certificate for the domain is valid, your container just doesn't trust the CA because it doesn't have those certificates locally

[image: helm.dask.org cert info]

Comment: I just run `yum install -y ca-certificates` but the output was that ca-certificates are already installed. I have also tries `update-ca-trust`, but no luck.

Comment: with this `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` the add repo work.

Comment: Maybe try retriving the certificate from the host using this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/192731/625369

Then append it to your truststore by adding another RUN command to the Dockerfile?
cat foo.crt >>/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Comment: You may need to use a different path, I just assumed CentOS since you mentioned yum

Comment: An update-ca-trust for good measure after you've appended to your bundle is also recommended (required?).